# Speeding-up a script by avoiding unnecessary repeated calculations in a nested for-for-if loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, for-loop, if-statement

Let's assume there are ~10**2 circles of known positions and radii. Also, assume there are ~10**3 points of known positions. The distribution being completely random, we know that if we probe each circle, in principle, it can have more than 1 point in it.

The following piece of python code is intended to loop over circles first and then over points. The way it's written, for each circle, the inner loop will calculate extraneous lines repeatedly if one only aims to keep track of circles which have at least 1 point.

For example, if one circle happens to have 100 points in it, the innermost loop will be run 100 times. But, I need to avoid this by manipulating the code such that, the moment one point is found inside a circle, the loop stop checking that circle for the rest of points. This way, I would tremendously increase the speed of my code. However, I am not exactly sure how to do the trick.

```
# position_data and radius_data are the properties of the circles mentioned above
for circle_position, circle_radius in zip(position_data, radius_data): 

    #(x, y) are the coordinates of the points mentioned above
    for x, y in zip(vals1, vals2):   

        if (condition1 and condition2 and condition3):
            # do some stuff  (these are the stuff that I want to avoid due to repetition)
```

Comment: If your conditions are met, you can do whatever you need to do, then `break`. This will exit the inner for loop and go immediately to the next circle.

Comment: @martineau, thank you for your input. I am embarrassed not to know the power of "break" even though I like to take it when I am at work :) ---Sincerely,

Comment: Ash: @schwartz721 posted the comment that answered your question, not me.

Comment: I know you already accepted a solution, but it might be worth sharing more, if not all of your program.

Comment: @AMC, thank you for recommendation, Here are some snapshots of the ongoing project I am working on for my thesis, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58637350/speed-up-a-long-python-code-that-proves-to-be-slow-only-due-to-a-single-block and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496844/speed-up-nested-if-loops-under-a-for-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the break statement? 
See [Python break and continue](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue).

In your conditional statement check if a point was found inside a circle and break when true, code below:

```
# position_data and radius_data are the properties of the circles mentioned above
for circle_position, circle_radius in zip(position_data, radius_data): 

    #(x, y) are the coordinates of the points mentioned above
    for x, y in zip(vals1, vals2):   

        # Condition to check if a point was found within a circle
        if point_in_circle(circle_position, circle_radius, x, y):
            break
```

For this conditional statement I would recommend pulling the point_in_circle check into a separate function for readability and re-usability:

```
def point_in_circle(cx, cy, cr, px, py):
    d = math.sqrt(
        (px - cx) ** 2 + (py - cy) ** 2
    )

    if d < cr:
        return True
```

Here, cx, cy, and cr are the circle's x position, y position, and radius respectively.

px, py are the point's x and y positions.

---

To help answer your follow up question I've pasted the code below, less some comments:

```
# NEW
pointsWithinCircles = 0
totalPoints = len(vals1)

def point_in_circle(position_data, radius_data, x, y):
    in_circle = False
    # Logic

    return in_circle

for circle_position, circle_radius in zip(position_data, radius_data):

    for x, y in zip(vals1, vals2):

        if point_in_circle(circle_position, circle_radius, x, y):

            # NEW - Increment counter
            pointsWithinCircles += 1
            break

#NEW
pointsOutsideCircles = totalPoints - pointsWithinCircles
```

You can create a counter to track how many points are contained within circles. Then, subtract the **pointsWithinCircles** from the total amount of points you have, which is simply the length of your vals1 (or vals2) list.

Comment: Dear Flavio, is it possible (within the same code) to count number of points that are contained by any single circle, meaning they are outside all circles?

Comment: Can you point me to a book so it can help me think like a code developer?

Comment: I think a good place to start would be [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm). Their tutorials and exercises are spot on for building a good foundation (not just in python but pretty much everything else). Further to that, they include [resources](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_useful_resources.htm) for further reading.